# Angular 2 remove duplicate values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am having an array of objects and want to remove duplicates

[image]

Like in the image i want to remove all duplicate values and get only single values and for the duplicates increase the quantity.

Comment: If you are using observables then use Distinct operator. Or use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: I am not using jquery

Comment: There is JS version too

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are implementing how to add items in your cart. I assume you have a product class or similar name to create your objects.

```
export class Product {
  constructor(
    public name: string, public amount: number, quantity: number, productId: string){} 
}
```

I suggest you implement another class, say cart.

```
export class Cart {
    constructor(
        public product: Product, public quantity: number) {}
}
```

In your service.ts,

```
carts: Cart[];

addToCart(product: Product) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.carts.length; i++) {
        if(this.carts[i].product.productId == product.productId) {
            this.carts[i].quantity = this.carts[i].quantity + 1;
            return;
        }// this code here to avoid duplicates and increase qty.
    }

    let cart = new Cart(product, 1);
    this.carts.push(cart);
}
```

You should have 3 different items in your cart, cs(3), dota(1), nfs(1). In my shopping cart, only 1 per item is added to cart, when you click on the product in my products component.

```
for(let i=0; i<products.length; i++){
  this.addToCart(products[i]);
}
```

This code works as show below

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `arr` is the array you want to remove duplicated from, here is a simple code to remove duplicated from it;

```
arr = Array.from(new Set(arr.map(x => {
  let obj;
  try {
    obj = JSON.stringify(x);
  } catch (e) {
    obj = x;
  }
  return obj;
}))).map(x => {
  let obj;
  try {
    obj = JSON.parse(x);
  } catch (e) {
    obj = x;
  }
  return obj;
});
```

Now, `arr` has no duplicates.

Comment: Using JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() seems like a risky way to assume uniqueness. Example: `var foo = { a: 1, b: 2 }; var bar = { b: 2, a: 1 };`.

Comment: Object property order is not guaranteed so yes, I'd say it matters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order
A unique identifier in a hashtable is much more reliable, and happily it looks like the the OP has an id property to work with.